# Запятая перед А

Tags: союзы

В предложении «Ну так а мне так не комфортно» нужна запятая перед союзом А?

Answer (score 2):

Частица *ну* и союз *так* придают выразительности фразе, но она полноценна и без них. ***Отделять их совсем не нужно,*** а то можно будет только споткнуться об эту запятую, ведь паузы мы не делаем тут.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в этом предложении "ну" и "[так](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA)" являются частицами.
И еще я думаю, что два слова "так" — многовато (совсем уж просторечно получается).
Запятая перед "а" не требуется.
Кстати, в определенном контексте "а" тоже можно посчитать частицей, усилительной.

Я бы написала это предложение таким образом:
*Ну а мне так не комфортно.* (Раздельно с *не* при условии отрицания комфортности.)

*Может вам она, как кляча,

**Ну а мне так** в самый раз.*
В. Высоцкий. Про речку Вачу и попутчицу Валю

["А" в предложении](https://znanieinfo.ru/punktuatsiya/zapyataya-pered-i-posle-soyuza-a.html)